# Is there any way to keep text passed to head, tail, less, etc. to be colored?

Tags: linux, pipe, gnome-terminal

Is there any way to keep colorization of text passed through pipe `|` to `head`, `tail`, `less`, etc.?

Comment: Any specific output program? It depends on the program sending the data through the pipe. `head`, `tail`, etc aren't the ones removing the colors, it's the program generating the data that usually check if the output is going to the console (colored), a file or pipe (not colored).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I presume you are piping from `ls` and want to preserve the terminal color codes. You can say `ls --color=always` (instead of the default of `--color=auto`), which will preserve the codes, but that won't guarantee that the thing you're piping to knows how to understand them.

If you use `glark` instead of `grep` it will try to display with colors.

If you use `less` with `-R` it will attempt to display with colors.

Comment: I'm piping from `git`. I'v found that it has similar configuration (eg. `git config color.diff always`) that keeps colorization.

Comment: @Errandir the problem with that configuration is that it will break any script or command that use `git diff` output as input because it will always output the ANSI escape codes.

Comment: @Errandir, thanks ! I do not have any scripts which rely on a clean output from git diff so this works for me !!  Thank you !

Comment: I used this for grep: `grep "string" file.txt | head` to make sure the result from grep was colored I just changed this to `grep "string" file.txt --color=always | head`

Comment: `git branch` has a `--color=always` option too.

Comment: It seems that various `git` subcommands have different ways to enable this: A separate answer dedicated to coloring `git` output: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18304605/245966

Answer (score 23):

It depends on the program that generate the output in the pipe.

`head`, `tail`, etc aren't the ones removing the colors, it's the program generating the data that usually check if the output is going to the console (colored), a file or pipe (not colored)

I found [another SU Q&A](https://superuser.com/a/385799/83522) showing how to lie to piping programs to output as if they were sending output to a console (emulating a console with `unbuffer`)

Comment: Is there any way to keep colorization in `color=auto` mode (to make program think that output goes to console instead of pipe)?

Comment: @KurzedMetal How does a program, for example `head`, `tail`, etc., detects that it is being piped to another program (so that it can generate data without colors, etc).

Comment: @JorgeBucaran http://stackoverflow.com/a/7601564/236871

Answer (score 0):

#### Consider

`bat`

#### An alternative to

`cat`

##### Install

`brew install bat`

##### --args --flags like

`--language` and `--theme`

##### Examples

```sh
head | bat --language=zsh -n -p --theme=gruvbox-dark
```

```py
file.py | bat --language=py -n -p --theme=gruvbox-dark
```

Comment: In all fairness, it is not preserving color, it's adding new color based on whatever language its piped and theme assigned.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X `man ls` mentions the `CLICOLOR_FORCE` environment variable.

Adding `export CLICOLOR_FORCE=1` to `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc`, depending on the shell you use, keeps the colors when piping `ls` to other commands like `less`, `head`, and `tail`.